# Request: Add How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example topic to the help center

Tags: feature-request

Can we add a new topic to the "Asking" section of the help center, Basically the same as this one for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

And have the ability to edit so we can customize specific to our site.